EMR-Spark Job creating max 1000 partitions/task when AQE is enabled
I see always 1000 task/partitions getting created for a spark jobs with AQE enabled. If I execute job for monthly(4 times weekly data) or a week data, the shuffle partitions are same.Whis is nothing but number of task running is 1000. Hence it's throwing memory issues. Is there any parameter enables max 1000 partitions.
Saprk submit:
As part of AQE, I have not enabled spark.sql.shuffle.partitions. Rather
spark-submit --conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=268435456 \ --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \ --conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \ --conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true \ --conf spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes=64m \ --conf spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled=true \ --conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.minPartitionNum=30000 \




check spark.sql.shuffle.partitions param, it sets number of partitions after each shuffle stage. Most likely it is set to 1000 for you. It can be set in default config for spark cluster, in job config when you submit it or hardcoded in code when you create spark session. You can check it in Spark UI Environment tab.

As part of AQE, I have not enabled spark.sql.shuffle.partitions. Rather spark-submit --conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=268435456 
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false 
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true 
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes=64m 
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled=true 
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.minPartitionNum=30000 \

Default value in EMR-spark cluster have spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum=1000, which was limiting 1000. Please look at thi slink below.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-performance.html
